# Perl epoch returns different values on 2 different machines (UTC and CET)

Tags: perl, time, timezone

I have 2 linux machines that need to run a perl script and access a database. 
For any reason, date itself is correct, but returning epoch from Perl has 1 hour difference resulting in having on one machine UTC epoch-timestamp and on the other the wanted CET.

date on A:

> Tue Dec 11 13:34:09 CET 2012

date on B:

> Tue Dec 11 13:33:20 CET 2012

To check whats going on I build a minimalistic example.
The script uses Time::HiRes and gathering the localtime->epoch to generate a date.
I build a minimalistic following script to output the behaviour:

```
#/usr/bin/perl
#
use Time::HiRes qw(time);
use Time::Piece;
#
my $date = Time::Piece->strptime(localtime->epoch,"%s");
print "$date->datetime"."\n";
print $date->tzoffset."\n";
print $date->epoch."\n";
```

Output Machine A:

> Tue Dec 11 12:35:43 2012->datetime 
>   0 
>   1355229343

Output Machine B:

> Tue Dec 11 13:34:25 2012->datetime 
>   0 
>   1355232865

So as you see something must be wrong with timezone or so. The differ with an hour. But I don't know where to look and what to configure as date itself outputs the correct time.

Comment: What does `perl -le'print time'` give?

Comment: Your script does not use Time::HiRes. (It loads the module, but doesn't use it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in `Time::Piece->strptime(STRING, FORMAT)`. Here is the code in question:

```
sub strptime {
    my $time = shift;
    my $string = shift;
    my $format = @_ ? shift(@_) : "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z";
    my @vals = _strptime($string, $format);
```

Let's start here. `_strptime` is the operating system's [native `strptime` function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/strptime.html). It appears to return local time, although that's not documented anywhere.

```
#    warn(sprintf("got vals: %d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d\n", reverse(@vals)));
    return scalar $time->_mktime(\@vals, (ref($time) ? $time->[c_islocal] : 0));
```

Okay, so we use our `_mktime` method to turn the output of `_strptime` into a `Time::Piece` object. The second parameter is whether `_mktime` should interpret as local time or UTC. When called as `Time::Piece->strptime(STRING, FORMAT)`, `ref($time)` will be false, and so `_mktime` will be called with `$islocal=0`, i.e. that `_strptime` returned a UTC time. This is wrong, and we've found the bug. (I don't know enough about the C time functions to know how it should be done.)

```
}
```

So you have to use `localtime->strptime(STRING, FORMAT)`. Except this will still fail on old versions of the module due to another bug in `_mktime` (my distribution comes with version 1.15 where this is still broken, but it's fixed in 1.20).

It's not even a strange issue specific to `%s`. It happens for any `Time::Piece->strptime` call:

```
$ perl -MTime::Piece -E'say $x=Time::Piece->strptime("11 Dec 2012 10:00","%d %b %Y %H:%M")->epoch;say scalar localtime $x'
1355220000
Tue Dec 11 04:00:00 2012
$ perl -MTime::Piece -E'say $x=localtime->strptime("11 Dec 2012 10:00","%d %b %Y %H:%M")->epoch;say scalar localtime $x'
1355220000
Tue Dec 11 04:00:00 2012
$ export PERL5LIB=Time-Piece-1.20/blib/lib:Time-Piece-1.20/blib/arch
$ perl -MTime::Piece -E'say $x=Time::Piece->strptime("11 Dec 2012 10:00","%d %b %Y %H:%M")->epoch;say scalar localtime $x'
1355220000
Tue Dec 11 04:00:00 2012
$ perl -MTime::Piece -E'say $x=localtime->strptime("11 Dec 2012 10:00","%d %b %Y %H:%M")->epoch;say scalar localtime $x'
1355241600
Tue Dec 11 10:00:00 2012
```

Answer (score -2):

I suggest you try using `gmtime` instead of `localtime`.

---

Doesn't help:

```
>perl -MTime::Piece -E"say Time::Piece->strptime(localtime->epoch,'%s')->epoch;"
1355239881

>perl -MTime::Piece -E"say Time::Piece->strptime(gmtime->epoch,'%s')->epoch;"
1355239881

>perl -E"say time"
1355239881
```

Comment: That doesn't help. Compare `perl -E"say time"`, which is the correct value.