# How to make Time::Piece respect DST when converting localtime to UTC?

Tags: perl, datetime, dst

I want to convert a timestamp from localtime to GMT. I have legacy code that does this "manually" with `Time::Local::timelocal()` and `gmtime`. It works, but I don't like it and wanted to use `Time::Piece` instead. I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/411795/5830574) to do so (albeit they are converting the other way round, but I was able to replace `+` with `-` :-)).

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Local;
use Time::Piece;
use POSIX qw(strftime);

sub local_to_utc_timelocal
{
    my $local_ts = shift;
    my ( $year, $mon, $mday, $hour, $min, $sec ) 
        = ( $local_ts =~ /(\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d) (\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)/ );
    my $local_secs = Time::Local::timelocal( $sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon - 1, $year );
    return POSIX::strftime( '%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', gmtime($local_secs) );
}

sub local_to_utc_timepiece
{
    my $local_ts = shift;
    my $local_tp = Time::Piece->strptime( $local_ts, '%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' );
    my $utc_tp   = $local_tp - localtime->tzoffset(); # ***
    return $utc_tp->strftime('%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S');
}

my $local;

# DST in effect (April 19 2016):
$local = '16-04-19 14:30:00';
print "DST in effect:\n";
printf("utc(%s) = %s (using timelocal)\n", $local, local_to_utc_timelocal($local));
printf("utc(%s) = %s (using timepiece)\n\n", $local, local_to_utc_timepiece($local));

# DST NOT in effect (Feb 19 2016):
$local = '16-02-19 14:30:00';
print "DST NOT in effect:\n";
printf("utc(%s) = %s (using timelocal)\n", $local, local_to_utc_timelocal($local));
printf("utc(%s) = %s (using timepiece)\n", $local, local_to_utc_timepiece($local));
```

Unfortunately the Time::Piece code doesn't seem to work properly wrt DST. I'm living in Germany, so currently (spring/summer, DST in effect) we are UTC+2. For "April 19 2016" the above code gives:

```
DST in effect:
utc(16-04-19 14:30:00) = 16-04-19 12:30:00 (using timelocal)
utc(16-04-19 14:30:00) = 16-04-19 12:30:00 (using timepiece)
```

which is correct. But for "Feb 19 2016" (when we are UTC+1) the same code gives:

```
DST NOT in effect:
utc(16-02-19 14:30:00) = 16-02-19 13:30:00 (using timelocal)
utc(16-02-19 14:30:00) = 16-02-19 12:30:00 (using timepiece)
```

That is: The `gmtime(Time::Local::timelocal($timestamp))` gives correct 1 hour offset while `Time::Piece` still gives 2 hours offset.

Is this a bug in `Time::Piece` or do I use it wrongly?

I know there are plenty of ways to convert localtime to UTC but I'd like to use `Time::Piece` because of its simplicity. Plus I cannot use `DateTime` because that would involve deploying it on a dozen of production machines.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Problem 1

`localtime` returns now, so `localtime->tzoffset()` returns the offset for now. Change

```
my $utc_tp = $local_tp - localtime->tzoffset();
```

to

```
my $utc_tp = $local_tp - $local_tp->tzoffset();
```

However, that leaves `$utc_tp` flagged as a localtime, so you really want:

```
my $utc_tp = gmtime( $local_tp->epoch );
```

### Problem 2

Despite its name, `$local_tp` is not a local time, so `$local_tp->tzoffset()` is zero. Change

```
Time::Piece->strptime( $local_ts, '%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' )
```

to

```
localtime->strptime( $local_ts, '%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' );
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried your solution back and forth and it works perfect. I suspected the `localtime->tzoffset()` line but had no idea that `localtime->strptime()` is the _real_ solution.

Comment: To expand on "`$local_tp` is not a local time": if you call `strptime` as a class method (i.e. `Time::Piece->strptime`) and don't specify a timezone in the format with `%z` or `%Z`, UTC is assumed. On the other hand, if you call `strptime` as an object method (e.g. `localtime->strptime`), the object's timezone is used.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: I've been banging my head against the wall on this. The `localtime->strptime` technique just didn't work for me; it always gave me a UTC time. It turns out ([Perl epoch returns different values on 2 different machines (UTC and CET)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13821230/perl-epoch-returns-different-values-on-2-different-machines-utc-and-cet)) that I'm running an older version of perl (5.10) and there's a bug in Time::Piece. I've had to resort to using the form of `localtime` where I pass in arguments for month, day, year, etc., rather than using `strptime`.

Comment: @Bob H, You could also have upgraded your Time::Piece. Out of curiosity, what version of Time::Piece do you have?

Comment: I think I'm using v1.12 on the machine where it doesn't work and 1.20_01 on the machine where it does. My understanding is that Time::Piece is part of the core now. (Also, in my previous reply, I meant to say `timelocal` rather than `localtime`, but I can't figure out how to edit it.)