# Converting timestamp to GMT with POSIX

Tags: perl, timestamp, posix, gmt

Is it possible to convert a given timestamp to GMT in Perl using the POSIX module? Below is what I've tried, but not sure why the time is so far off...

```
use POSIX;
my $shipts = "2017-09-23 20:53:00";
my $shiptsgmt = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %R", localtime(str2time($shipts, 'GMT')));
print "$shiptsgmt\n";
```

The localtime of the server is Pacific time, guess what I'm trying to do is not correct. The above produces 2017-09-23 13:53 and I need 2017-09-24 03:53 time.

Comment: use POSIX allows for str2time.

Comment: I don't see that in POSIX docs (v5.16 and v5.27) ...

Comment: @rwfitzy ? I have get `Undefined subroutine &main::str2time called at ...`

Comment: POSIX.pm doesn't have any date-parsing utilities; it's not the best suited module for the job.

Comment: Sorry, I see now it was actually coming from had Date::Parse used as well. Given this should be about that module instead of POSIX now, the solution was very simple to use gmtime instead of localtime as in gmtime(str2time($shipts)). Works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `POSIX` alone cannot do this, not without help from builtins and a little processing.

An alternative: [Time::Piece](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html) is core, and in my experience much quicker than POSIX

```
perl -MTime::Piece -wE'
    $d = "2017-09-23 20:53:00"; 
    $t = localtime->strptime($d, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
    $t = gmtime($t->epoch);
    say $t->strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
'
```

This creates an object and then converts it to GMT using the module's (compatible) replacement for `gmtime`, returing an object which is also suitably flagged as GMT.

The `strftime` is the same but much lighter than the POSIX extension and `strptime` is 
[from FreeBSD](http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/3/strftime/).
The module also has many methods to get various parts or representations of the datetime object as a string, along with a few other utilities. See also [Time::Seconds](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Seconds.html).

The [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-1.44/lib/DateTime.pm) does all this nicely, via its [formatters](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-1.44/lib/DateTime.pm#Formatters_And_Stringification) for parsing and stringification. But it is heavy.

---

**Note**   It is rather easy to end up using this module incorrectly, and this answer did just that before [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) fixed it. So please be very careful with any uses other than basic.  See linked answers

- [(answer): How to make Time::Piece respect DST when converting localtime to UTC?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36729129/4653379)
  for a full account of a possible DST-related error when converting time zones.
- [(answer): How can I parse dates and convert time zones in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/411795/4653379)
  which as it turns out in fact covers this question.

*Note that the answer above does not work in v5.10*, apparently due to a then-bug in the module.

Comment: @ikegami  Thank you. I've edited, with the info on your post that I now found which directly deals with that error (and another old post that this is apparently a dupe of). I'll add more suitable links if I find them. (I cleared some of my comments to make your warning more visible.)

Comment: @ikegami  If I may bug you with a question. I've written a utility subclassing `Time::Piece` (carefully!) for particular uses here, and it works like a charm.  But I could never find piece with this:  Are there any glitches to this module, with edge cases, DST, days-without-midnight, or such?  (Not counting trickiness and user errors.)  I am thinking of fairly basic uses, for world-wide datetimes within the last century or so.  I've searched and searched and found nothing to worry about but this is a tricky business.  While one can't ask something like that here :(

Comment: It uses `localtime` for time zone stuff, so no issues of interest there. The problem with T::P is that it's easy to do things incorrectly with it. It's an API design failure, not a bug in the code. Subclassing might inherit those problems. Encapsulation might not.

Comment: @ikegami  Thank you very much for clearing that finally!  And for the tip -- I got drawn to conveniencies but then I _am_ exposing the tricky parts this way, too (while I don't need all that).  It's time to time things..